# How do I repeat my program again in JS based on the user choice?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok I have a made a a little quiz using html, css, and JS. What I want to do is at the end of the quiz I would like to ask the user a choice whether they would like to re do the quiz again. I think I have to use a "while" loop but am not so sure. Ok I have added the html and the JS. I think it be easy to understand. I have added the eventlistener but it's not running properly and I don't know how to fix it. It gives me error message saying "addEventListener not a function".

```js
function Quiz(questions) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
    if(this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
        this.score++;
    }

    this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
    return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}


function Question(text, choices, answer) {
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
    return this.answer === choice;
}


function populate() {
    if(quiz.isEnded()) {
        showScores();
    }
    else {
        // show question
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        // show options
        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
            element.innerHTML = choices[i];
            guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }

        showProgress();
    }
};

function guess(id, guess) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function() {
        quiz.guess(guess);
        populate();
    }
};


function showProgress() {
    var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
    var element = document.getElementById("progress");
    element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function shuffle_questions(questions) {
    var currentIndex = questions.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        temporaryValue = questions[currentIndex];
        questions[currentIndex] = questions[randomIndex];
        questions[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return questions;
}

function restart() {
    document.getElementById("quiz").innerHTML = ''; // Clear out the "game over"
    questions = shuffle_questions(questions); // Left as an exercise for the reader; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array
    quiz = new Quiz(questions); // Rebuild the quiz object
    populate();
  
    return false; // So the link doesn't try to go anywhere
  }

function showScores() {
    var gameOverHTML = "<h1>Result</h1>";
    gameOverHTML += "<h2 id='score'> Your scores: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";
    // message if they would like to try again, should I use console.log?
    gameOverHTML.addEventListener("click", restart) //not done yet
    var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
    element.innerHTML = gameOverHTML;
};

// create questions here
var questions = [
    new Question("Which nation won FIFA 2018 World Cup?", ["Peru", "France","Germany", "USA"], "France"),
    new Question("Which nation hosted FIFA 2018 World Cup?", ["Sweden", "Russia", "Iran", "South Korea"], "Russia"),
    new Question("Which nation has won the most World Cups?", ["Argentina", "Peru","Brazil", "France"], "Brazil"),
    new Question("Where was FIFA 2014 World Cup hosted?", ["Ecuador", "Brazil", "France", "All"], "Brazil"),
    new Question("Which nation won the first FIFA World Cup", ["Brazil", "Uruguay", "Italy", "Australia"], "Uruguay")
];

// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="quiz">
            <h1>FIFA World Cup Quiz</h1>
            <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

            <p id="question"></p>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
                <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
            </div>

            <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
            <footer>
                <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>


<script src="question.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added a `<div id="results">` (hidden by default) which will be used to show the results. When the game ends, the `showScores()` function shows this `<div>` and hides the `<div id="quiz">`.

When the user clicks the `Restart` button, the handler hides the `<div id="results">` and shows the `<div id="quiz">` so the game can be played.

This can be improved by adding/removing classes rather than directly manipulating the CSS (`style.display` property). But that's left as an exercise for the reader.

You can also find this code here: https://jsfiddle.net/kjLbea61/

```js
function Quiz(questions) {
    this.score = 0;
    this.questions = questions;
    this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
    return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
    if(this.getQuestionIndex().isCorrectAnswer(answer)) {
        this.score++;
    }

    this.questionIndex++;
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
    return this.questionIndex === this.questions.length;
}


function Question(text, choices, answer) {
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
}

Question.prototype.isCorrectAnswer = function(choice) {
    return this.answer === choice;
}


function populate() {
    if(quiz.isEnded()) {
        showScores();
    }
    else {
        // show question
        var element = document.getElementById("question");
        element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;

        // show options
        var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
        for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
            var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
            element.innerHTML = choices[i];
            guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
        }

        showProgress();
    }
};

function guess(id, guess) {
    var button = document.getElementById(id);
    button.onclick = function() {
        quiz.guess(guess);
        populate();
    }
};


function showProgress() {
    var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
    var element = document.getElementById("progress");
    element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + " of " + quiz.questions.length;
};

function shuffle_questions(questions) {
    var currentIndex = questions.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;

        temporaryValue = questions[currentIndex];
        questions[currentIndex] = questions[randomIndex];
        questions[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return questions;
}

function restart() {
    questions = shuffle_questions(questions); // Left as an exercise for the reader; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array
    quiz = new Quiz(questions); // Rebuild the quiz object
    populate();
    
    document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = 'block'; // show quiz
    document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'none'; // hide results
  }

function showScores() {
    document.getElementById('quiz').style.display = 'none'; // hide quiz
    document.getElementById('results').style.display = 'block'; // show results

    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = quiz.score; // Put score in results
};

// create questions here
var questions = [
    new Question("Which nation won FIFA 2018 World Cup?", ["Peru", "France","Germany", "USA"], "France"),
    new Question("Which nation hosted FIFA 2018 World Cup?", ["Sweden", "Russia", "Iran", "South Korea"], "Russia"),
    new Question("Which nation has won the most World Cups?", ["Argentina", "Peru","Brazil", "France"], "Brazil"),
    new Question("Where was FIFA 2014 World Cup hosted?", ["Ecuador", "Brazil", "France", "All"], "Brazil"),
    new Question("Which nation won the first FIFA World Cup", ["Brazil", "Uruguay", "Italy", "Australia"], "Uruguay")
];

document.getElementById('restart').addEventListener('click', restart);

// create quiz
var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

// display quiz
populate();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
        <div id="quiz">
            <h1>FIFA World Cup Quiz</h1>
            <hr style="margin-bottom: 20px">

            <p id="question"></p>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
                <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
                <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
                <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
            </div>

            <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
            <footer>
                <p id="progress">Question x of y</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
        <div id="results" style="display: none">
          <h1>
            Results
          </h1>
          <h2>
            Your scores: <span id="score"></span>
          </h2>
          <button id="restart">
            Restart
          </button>
        </div>
        
    </div>


<!--
<script src="question.js"></script>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow thanks @kmoser!!! I have another question, for the shuffling part do I make another separate function? Or do I make within the restart function?

Comment: @sgibson19 You could do it either way. It's always nice to separate out tasks into separate functions to keep each function small so I would suggest doing it my way.

Comment: I have added the addeventlistener but it is not working, thank you so much for your help so far. I hope I don't annoy you with all this questions.

Comment: You're trying to add an event listener to a string, which won't work. You have several more problems you need to address first, most notably that when the game ends you remove the entire contents of the `<div id="quiz">`, including the `<p id="question">` which is required when you repopulate the game. Instead of removing the contents of that div, hide it and show the contents of a "game over" div instead. Then when the user clicks to play again, you can show the main div and hide the "game over div".

Comment: Ok will try to do that. But honestly am completely lost on how to solve this. Thanks for your help @kmoser

Comment: Give it your best shot! I'll also do it and put it up on a Fiddle, but you'll learn more by trying it yourself first.

Comment: yea I have tried my best and I still can't figure it out.

Comment: I've updated my code so it works the way you intended. There's also a link to a JSFiddle.

Comment: THANK YOU @kmoser. Wow looking at it makes so much sense, one of the main issues I was having is that I was using the "addEventListener" within the "showScores" function. Can't tell you how relieve I am, been trying to solve this for the last 2 days, thanks for everything.

Comment: @qTips You're welcome! If my answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and/or marking it as the accepted answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers